# How to change a node of a XML file to a node present in another XML file using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

one XML file has

```
<x1>
<x2>xyz</x2>
<x3>xy</x3>
<x4>z</x4>
<x5>123</x5>
</x1>
```

Another XML has

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <c>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <XMLFieldName>UserDetails</XMLFieldName>
  </c>
  <c>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <XMLFieldName>UserName</XMLFieldName>
  </c>
  <c>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <XMLFieldName>FirstName</XMLFieldName>
  </c>
  <c>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <XMLFieldName>LastName</XMLFieldName>
  </c>
  <c>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <XMLFieldName>EmployeeID</XMLFieldName>
  </c>
</DocumentElement>
```

And I want to get resultant XML as

```
<UserDetails>
<UserName>xyz</UserName>
<FirstName>xy</FirstName>
<LastName>z</LastName>
<EmployeeID>123</EmployeeID>
</UserDetails>
```

More Information: Actually 1st and 2nd files are in DB Table as XML dataType.
and i just need a XSLT to get the 3rd XML and X1,x2.... nodes are based on the tag ID.

ThanQ in Advance..:-)

Comment: Here is a similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759871/re-order-xml-elements-in-a-specific-way-using-xslt/15759961?noredirect=1#comment22399245_15759961

Maybe it can help

Comment: Thank you. But its a kinda different. Here I want to change the tag/ Node of an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one XSLT 1.0 compatible option:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!--
  Pass the name of the other XML file as a parameter to the transformation;
  x1.xml is used by default
  -->
  <xsl:param name="x1" select="'x1.xml'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Only apply the first <c> element -->
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="DocumentElement/c[XMLFieldName = 'UserDetails']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c[XMLFieldName = 'UserDetails']">
    <!-- Use the value of the XMLFieldName element as the element name -->
    <xsl:element name="{XMLFieldName}">
      <!-- Apply following <c> siblings -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::c"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c">
    <!-- Save the value of the ID child of current <c> element -->
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="ID"/>

    <xsl:element name="{XMLFieldName}">
      <!--
      Get the value of the element in x1.xml that has the same number in its
      element name as the value of the <ID> child of this <c> element
      -->
      <xsl:value-of
        select="document($x1)/*/*[substring-after(local-name(), 'x') = $id]"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <c>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <XMLFieldName>UserDetails</XMLFieldName>
  </c>
  <c>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <XMLFieldName>UserName</XMLFieldName>
  </c>
  <c>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <XMLFieldName>FirstName</XMLFieldName>
  </c>
  <c>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <XMLFieldName>LastName</XMLFieldName>
  </c>
  <c>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <XMLFieldName>EmployeeID</XMLFieldName>
  </c>
</DocumentElement>
```

#### x1.xml

```
<x1>
  <x2>xyz</x2>
  <x3>xy</x3>
  <x4>z</x4>
  <x5>123</x5>
</x1>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserDetails>
  <UserName>xyz</UserName>
  <FirstName>xy</FirstName>
  <LastName>z</LastName>
  <EmployeeID>123</EmployeeID>
</UserDetails>
```

Comment: Thank you Eero... But I am getting an error in xslt.. it says....Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it. An error occurred at D:\ex4.xsl(32,7).

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with .NET. You might find [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2710649/825783) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltsettings.enabledocumentfunction.aspx) helpful.

Comment: Can anybody help me in exporting XML data saved in a MySQL database     <x1>
<x2>xyz</x2>
<x3>xy</x3>
<x4>z</x4>
<x5>123</x5>
</x1>to an external file as x1.xml or x1.txt using C#?

Comment: Can anybody help me in exporting XML data saved in a MySQL database <x1> <x2>xyz</x2> <x3>xy</x3> <x4>z</x4> <x5>123</x5> </x1> to an external file as x1.xml or x1.txt using C#?

Comment: @user2244927: Please submit a new question instead of commenting on this one.

Comment: I submitted a new question based on the above comment::  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079023/exporting-xml-data-present-in-database-to-an-external-xml-file-using-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment22952730_16079023